# ggplot2 geom_bar gives error when position="fill" in some scenarios

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm getting an error when trying to use position="fill" for a geom_bar.  Here's a MWE:

```
temp = data.frame( X=rep(1:10,10), weight=runif(100), fill=rbinom(100,size=3,p=.5) )
temp$weight[temp$fill==3] = 0
ggplot( temp, aes(x=X, weight=weight, fill=as.factor(fill)) ) +
  geom_bar(bin_width=1)
ggplot( temp, aes(x=X, weight=weight, fill=as.factor(fill)) ) +
  geom_bar(bin_width=1,position="fill")
```

The first ggplot call works fine, producing a bar plot where each bar is composed of 3 colors corresponding to levels 0,1, and 2.  The legend shows the final level (3), but as the weight is always 0, it doesn't appear on the plot.

However, the second ggplot call returns an error.  I had expected it to return the same plot as before but just scale each bar's height up to 1.  Any idea why this is happening, and if there's a work-around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that it expects `weight` to be > 0 when you use `position=fill`. If you do:

```
ggplot(temp[temp$weight > 0,], 
    aes(x=X, weight=weight, fill=factor(fill))) + 
    geom_bar(bin_width=1, position="fill")
```

then it works.